# Scraping data with Python and receiving different html tree than in DevTools

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to **scrape** data from site zara.com,
I'm already figure out how to parse parent elements with group of items in a list, but I want to dig deeper and open each item-link and grab additional information about it.

So, I used this kind of code for it:

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



ListWithRequests = ['https://www.zara.com/nl/en/plain-shirt-p06608389.html'] # In this example only one item

for item in ListWithRequests:
    
    response = requests.get(item,verify=False)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    soup2.prettify()
    time.sleep(1)
    f = open("demo.html","w+")
    f.write(response.text)
```

For example I want to receive the price of the item, in the dev tools it's block

```
<span class="main_price">25.95 EUR</span>
```

or Item ID

```
<div clas="product-info-wrapper _product-info">
  <p class="product-color">
    <span class="_colorName">**White**
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

But in the **demo.html** file I'm receiving completely different tree, and can't find any elements that I need.

Please, advice what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page is loaded via `JavaScript`, Therefore `bs4` will not be able to render it. you can use `selenium` for such cases, But i noticed that the data which you looking for it, is actually presented within `script` tag, which you can easily load it with `JSON` or for a quick catch, I've used `re`:

```py
import requests
import re


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    price = re.search(r'\"price\": \"(.*?)\"', r.text).group(1)
    print(price)


main("https://www.zara.com/nl/en/plain-shirt-p06608389.html")
```

Output:

```
25.95
```